# Sound not replaying on onTouchListener

Tags: java, android

So I have a button that, when held, will play a sound. However, it does not seem to "reset" and never plays that sound again when I hold down the button again. I get a

E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 0
E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (-38, 0)

error in log when I try to hold the button down again. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  final MediaPlayer bark = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bark);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    playSound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    playSound.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if(!bark.isPlaying()) bark.start();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(bark.isPlaying()) bark.stop();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: U forgot the Permissions?

Comment: Can you show me what permissions I would need in the manifest please?

Comment: Set looping to true and call prepare just after creating the media player

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling start/stop you can call start/pause with `seekTo()`:

```
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(!bark.isPlaying()) bark.start();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if(bark.isPlaying()){
                bark.pause();
                bark.seekTo(0);
                }
                break;
```

If you want to use start/stop, make sure you call prepare() before calling start() again.

The reason why your code isn't working is because according to the [state diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram) stop() stops playing and puts the MP in a stopped state. Before starting to play for the next time, you should call prepare() and then start() again.

**EDIT :**  Place your music file in the assets folder and use the file descriptor. This way you can reset the MP and replay:

Using START/STOP:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
AssetManager assetManager=Context.getAssets();
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd("bark.mp3"); //replace with right extension
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
playSound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
playSound.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if(!bark.isPlaying()){
                     bark.reset();
                    bark.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());
                    bark.prepare();
                    bark.start();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if(bark.isPlaying())
                    bark.stop();                        
                    break;
         }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked and I would upvote you if I had enough rep! For some reason, calling prepare() before start() does not work, even if i put prepare() after stop()